# ng-repeat adding a 0 element to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm creating an array in a service and fetch some data from a db and iterative over the data to add the group id as a key in the array

```
angular.module('tasksApp').
factory("data", ["$http", function ($http) {

    var data = {};
    data.allTasks = {};
    data.today = [];
    data.actioned = [];
    data.complete = [];
    data.todaysNextNumber = 0;
    data.groups = [];
    data.groupNames = [];
    data.nextGroupPosition = [];


    data.loadTasks = function () {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/loadTasks'})
      .then(function(response) {
        data.allTasks = response.data;
        // Get groups & create the arrays
        getGroups().then(function(result) {
          var allGroups = result;
          for (var key in allGroups) {
            var group = allGroups[key];
            data.groups[group.group_id] = [];
            data.groupNames[group.group_id] = group.group_name;
            data.nextGroupPosition[group.group_id] = 0;
          }
```

The id's of the data start with 1 and go up to 9.

Then, in the component I load the data to the scope:

```
angular.module('tasksApp').
component('tasks', {
templateUrl: 'tasks/template.tasks.html',
controller: function startUp($scope, $rootScope, data) {
  // Get tasks
  data.loadTasks().then(function(response) {
    $scope.groups = data.groups;
    $scope.today = data.today;
    $scope.actioned = data.actioned;
    $scope.groupNames = data.groupNames;
    console.log($scope.groups);
  })
}
```

});

and use ng-repeat to go over the data in the template:

```
<!-- Start of Groups -->
<div ng-repeat="(key, group) in groups" class="col-md-3">
  <div class="groupBox">
    <div ng-attr-id="{{'groupCell-' + key}}" ng-click="showTitleInput(key)">
      <h1 ng-attr-id="{{'groupTitle-' + key}}">{{groupNames[key]}} - {{key}}</h1>
      <input class="groupTitleInput" ng-attr-id="{{'groupInput-' + key}}" ng-value="groupNames[key]"></input></div>

      <div ng-attr-id="{{'div' + key}}">
        <div ng-repeat="task in group | orderBy:'position'" ng-attr-id="{{'task-' + task.id}}" class="taskContainer">
          <div ng-attr-id="{{'taskText-' + task.id}}" class="taskText" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar">{{task.task}}</div>
          <div ng-attr-id="{{'actionBar-' + task.id}}" class="actionBar" ng-show="displayActionBar">
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-globe todaysTasks" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar; addToToday(task.id, task.group_id)"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-ok actioned" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar; markAsActioned(task.id, task.group_id)"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up complete" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar; markAsComplete(task.id, task.group_id)"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar; deleteTask(task.id, task.group_id)"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-remove cancel" ng-click="displayActionBar = !displayActionBar"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up up" ng-click="pushUp(task.id, task.group_id)"></div>
            <div class="actionButton glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down down" ng-click="pushDown(task.id, task.group_id)"></div></div></div></div>
    <form ng-submit="addTask(key)" ><input name={{key}} class="newTaskInput" type="text" ng-model="newTaskDescription" /><form></div></div>
```

All this works fine but when the data is displayed a div for an '0' element is shown.  If I print the array out using console.log it doesn't show a '0' element. Also, if I change the data with the id of 1 to 0 it also iterates over a 1 element. I thought that ng-repeat iterated over the elements in the array using the assigned key, not going from 0 through to the number of elements.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I'd try this `data.groups = {}`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!